# Can Keras ImageDataGenerator transform label points (x,y) accordinlgy to performed augmentation?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, keras

I am solving supervised learning problem with keras. My training data is input `x` = image and output `Y` = a vector of six integers, representing three 2D points on the image (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3).

I'm trying to use Keras ImageDataGenerator for image augmentation however there are some transformations (like resize) that will affect the positions of points I an using as ground truth. Therefore I need to also transform my labels (points) accordingly to whatever transformations were performed by ImageDataGenerator.

Is there a support for that in Keras? As I cannot find any method that I could use for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data Augmentation Image Data Generator Keras Semantic Segmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155836/data-augmentation-image-data-generator-keras-semantic-segmentation)

Comment: Actually, probably a duplicate of: [How to customize ImageDataGenerator in order to modify the target variable values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758592/how-to-customize-imagedatagenerator-in-order-to-modify-the-target-variable-value)