# How to customize ImageDataGenerator in order to modify the target variable values?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset of images annotated with coordinates representing facial keypoints. As I would like to augment the dataset, I am looking for a way to implement the ImageDataGenerator to modify the target variables according to image transformation (for example, if the image is flipped horizontally, the x coordinates should be set to image_width - x or if the image is padded, the x coordinates should be set to x - padding.

I would be thankful for any suggestion or resource that might illustrate any similar example.

Thanks,

Niko

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most obvious way is to modify the Keras code (you can find full implementation of [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) in [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py)). However, Keras does provide an **elegant API** to deal with this, although it is not very well documented.

## Writing a generator

We would need to write a new Keras generator, inheriting from [`Iterator`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py#L22) class. The [`Iterator`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/iterator.py#L22) class itself is just a convenient child class from [`Sequence`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence), a detailed tutorial of which can be found [here](https://stanford.edu/%7Eshervine/blog/keras-how-to-generate-data-on-the-fly).

```python
from keras.preprocessing.image import Iterator, ImageDataGenerator


class MyIterator(Iterator):
  """This is a toy example of a wrapper around ImageDataGenerator"""

  def __init__(self, n, batch_size, shuffle, seed, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(n, batch_size, shuffle, seed)

    # Load any data you need here (CSV, HDF5, raw stuffs). The code
    # below is just a pseudo-code for demonstration purpose.
    input_images = ...
    ground_truth = ...

    # Here is our beloved image augmentator <3
    self.generator = ImageDataGenerator(**kwargs)
    
  def _get_batches_of_transformed_samples(self, index_array):
    """Gets a batch of transformed samples from array of indices"""

    # Get a batch of image data
    batch_x = input_images[index_array].copy()
    batch_y = ground_truth[index_array].copy()

    # Transform the inputs and correct the outputs accordingly
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(batch_x, batch_y)):
      transform_params = self.generator.get_random_transform(x.shape)
      batch_x[i] = self.generator.apply_transform(x, transform_params)
      batch_y[i] = process_outputs_accordingly(y, transform_params)

    return batch_x, batch_y
```

## Why we inherit from Keras Iterator?

It is recommended to have your generators inherited from [`keras.utils.Sequence`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) (also the base class of other classes). It allows the data be loaded in parallel between several threads.

## I want the same training API!

You can write a custom generator with methods `flow`, `flow_from_directory`, and `flow_from_dataframe` --- core functions of Keras API.

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate how to create a Keras Image Generator that will **modify the target labels** when an image is flipped, I have created a GitHub repo at: https://github.com/frobertpixto/tf_keras_generator_with_targets

The repo contains:

- A Jupyter notebook with the Generator class and calls to the Generator to illustrate the data augmentation.
- An example of how to call `model.fit` using the Generator