# Keras: poor performance with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, image, keras, computer-vision, data-augmentation

I try to augment my image data using the Keras `ImageDataGenerator`. My task is a regression task, where an input image results in another, transformed image. So far so good, works quite well.

Here I wanted to apply data augmentation by using the `ImageDataGenerator`. In order to transform both images the same way, I used the approach described in the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), where a transformation of an image with a corresponding mask is described. My case is a little bit different, as my images are already loaded and don't need to be fetched from a directory. This procedure was already described in [another StackOverlow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155836/data-augmentation-image-data-generator-keras-semantic-segmentation).

To verify my implementation, I first used it without augmentation and using the `ImageDataGenerator` without any parameter specified. According to the class reference in the [Keras docs](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), this should not alter the images. See this snippet:

```
img_val = img[0:split_seperator]
img_train = img[split_seperator:]

target_val = target[0:split_seperator]
target_train = target[split_seperator:]

data_gen_args = dict()

# define data preparation
src_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
target_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

# fit parameters from data
seed = 1
src_datagen.fit(img_train, augment=False, seed=seed)
target_datagen.fit(target_train, augment=False, seed=seed)

training_generator = zip(
    src_datagen.flow(img_train, batch_size=batch_size_training, seed=seed),
    target_datagen.flow(target_train, batch_size=batch_size_training, seed=seed))

_ = model.fit_generator(
    generator=training_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=image_train.shape[0] // batch_size_training,
    epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1,
    validation_data=(img_val, target_val), callbacks=callbacks)
```

Unfortunately, my implementation seems to have some issues. I do not get the performances expected. The validation loss is somehow stable around a certain value and only slightly decreasing (see the image below). Here I expect, as I did not use any augmentation, the same loss as the non-augmented baseline.

[image: Comparisson of validation loss]

In comparison, my training without the `ImageDataGenerator` looks like

```
_ = model.fit(img, target,
              batch_size=batch_size_training,
              epochs=num_epochs, verbose=1,
              validation_split=0.2, callbacks=cb)
```

I guess I got somehow mixed up with the usage of the `ImageDataGenerator`, the `flow` and the `fit` function. So my questions are:

- is one of the applied functions `fit` or `flow` redundant and causes this behavior?
- do I have an implementation problem?
- does this implementation in general makes sense?
- does it make sense to set the validation set fix or should it be augmented too?

**Update (2019-01-23 & cont.):**
What I have already tried so far (in responses to answers):

- creating an generator for the validation data as well
- removing the applied fit function
- setting `shuffle=True` in the flow function (data is already shuffled)

Neither of these approaches helped to make the results better.

Comment: Have you tried manually looking into what its mislabeling and what is the result after the mislabeling, Do you see a pattern there or is it all random, just have a look at few mislabeled data.

Comment: I have a regression task, where an image is transformed into another image. Here it is hard to see if it is mislabeled. The only thing I can say, is that the correct target image is used with the input image. The results look like I expect for such kind of loss.

Comment: Are you trying to use neural style transfer?

Comment: Not really. It is a supervised application in image processing.

Comment: @anand_v.singh  How could you load and augment images when pixels are already present in the Dataframe like in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59596784/custom-imagedatagenerator-for-half-a-million-images-where-labels-and-pixels-ar)? Could you please answer it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I understand what you are trying to do, this should get the job done.

```
aug = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)

# train the network
H = model.fit_generator(aug.flow(img_train, target_train, batch_size=image_train.shape[0]),
    validation_data=(img_val, target_val), steps_per_epoch=image_train.shape[0] // BS,
    epochs=EPOCHS)
```

Let me know if this works.